# knitr caching fails when using XeLaTeX fontspec package through RStudio

Tags: r, latex, knitr, rstudio, fontspec

I use knitr with XeLaTeX within RStudio. I use chunk caching so that I don't have to rerun certain code every time I compile my document. This minimal example shows that the caching appears to be broken if the `fontspec` package is loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % Appears to somehow conflict with caching.

\begin{document}

<<pre_load, cache=TRUE>>=
library(tikzDevice)
options(tikzDefaultEngine="xetex")
@

\section{Test}
<<test_block, dev='tikz', dependson='pre_load'>>=
plot(1:10,main='Test')
@

\end{document}
```

The first time this document is compiled to PDF, it will work, because caching is not used. However, if a change is made to the `test_block` chunk, and the code is run a second time, it will fail. For example, *after compiling to PDF once*, change the `test_block` chunk to:

```
<<test_block, dev='tikz', dependson='pre_load'>>=
plot(1:10,main='Test Modified')
@
```

Now, compiling to PDF fails with the following error:

```
! 
 ********************************************
 * XeTeX is required to compile this document.
 * Sorry!
 ********************************************.
\RequireXeTeX ...********************************}
                                                  \endgroup \fi 
l.18 \RequireXeTeX
```

This error indicates that `options(tikzDefaultEngine="xetex")` has not been set.  Interestingly, if the `fontspec` package is not loaded, then this error does not occur.

My question is: Is this a bug, or is there something wrong with my code?

I am using knitr (1.1) using tikzDevice (0.6.3) on R (R Under development (unstable) (2012-11-10 r61101)) through RStudio (0.97.246) (accessed via browser through RStudio Server) which itself is running on a Ubuntu (12.04.2 LTS). My LaTeX2e is dated <2009/09/24>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not put `options(tikzDefaultEngine="xetex")` in a cached chunk because it has a side-effect which cannot be cached, so the second time you compile the document, this option will be skipped. Read the section [Important Notes in the cache page](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/) on the `knitr` website.

Note you do not need to `library(tikzDevice)` either; this package will be automatically loaded when you set `dev='tikz'`.

In most cases, you should cache the plot chunk instead because it is slow to create TikZ graphics.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % Appears to somehow conflict with caching.

\begin{document}

<<pre_load>>=
options(tikzDefaultEngine="xetex")
@

\section{Test}
<<test_block, dev='tikz'>>=
plot(1:10,main='Test')
@

\end{document}
```